# Update Database according to the Date Entered

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, date

I have a row with three columns in my database i.e

> start_date = 2013-12-1
>   end_date = 2013-12-31
>   status = 'a'

I want to change the status for dates by adding a new record

> start_date = 2013-12-10
>   end_date = 2013-12-20
>   status = 'u'

In this case I can easily update database and updated database will be-

```
1)start_date = 2013-12-1
end_date = 2013-12-9
status = 'a'
2)start_date= 2013-12-10
end_date = 2013-12-20
status = 'u'
3)start_date = 2013-12-21
end_date = 2013-12-31
status = 'a'
```

But when I again want to change the status for the date :

> start_date = 2013-12-15
>   end_date = 2013-12-25
>   status= 'a'

So, I want such result in my database

```
1)start_date = 2013-12-1
end_date = 2013-12-9
status = 'a'
2)start_date = 2013-12-10
end_date = 2013-12-14
status = 'u'
3)start_date = 2013-12-15
end_date = 2013-12-25
status = 'a'
4)start_date = 2013-12-26
end_date = 2013-12-31
status = 'a'
```

So, how will I manage update query or any other way to do the same?

Comment: what status u and a indicates in this case?

Comment: u for unavailable and a for available

Comment: is there any other criteria except date to manage it?

Comment: no. i should do only through the date and its status

Comment: three rows mean are you talking about rows or column?

Comment: so you want to change status of all the dates which are greater than the first and today right?

Comment: these are my three records

Comment: i give exact example for this in my question

Comment: You say "I have 3 rows in database", probably you mean "I have 3 columns in a database table". See my answer below, I think you should improve your DB design a bit, then worry about the update statement. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to find where the record will be inserted, for example :

```
record   start date    end date    status
1        2013-12-1     2013-12-9   'a'
                  <-- the new record goes here (2013-12-15     2013-12-25    'a')
2        2013-12-10    2013-12-20  'u'
3        2013-12-21    2013-12-31  'a'
```

You can get that position by comparing new start date with existing start dates

```
$new_start_date = '2013-12-15';
$new_end_date   = '2013-12-25';

$result_before =  $mysqli->query('SELECT ... WHERE end_date < "$new_start_date"
                   ORDER BY end_date DESC LIMIT 1");
$result_after =  $mysqli->query('SELECT ... WHERE start_date < "$new_start_date"
                   ORDER BY end_date LIMIT 1");
```

I've left out the exact details of the query processing. You can fill in the details.

This will give you records  1 and 2, you know now that the record must be inserted between the 2 You can now update record 2, and insert the new record.

```
INSERT INTO table SET 
   start_date = DATE_ADD($result_before_end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) ,
    end_date  = $new_end_date

UPDATE table SET 
   start_date = DATE_ADD($new_end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
WHERE record = $result_after_record_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're representing in your DB segments of time 
like [DateFrom, DateTo, status]. And things get complicated 
when your segments overlap. What I suggest is that
you represent it this way [Date, status]. A year has just 
365-366 days so it's not that much data to store
(actually it's nothing for a serious RDBMS).

It would be easier for you if you represent each date
as a separate row in your DB. Then you would need to just 
update certain dates to 'u' and others to 'a' status. 
But your update queries will be much simpler.